# TcpListener port : socket gets created on different port

Tags: sockets, port, tcplistener

I am basically executing the following code:

```
int port = 5555; //just an example
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,port);
var l = new TcpListener(ep);
l.Start();
l.BeginAccept(AcceptHandler,l);
```

It works (of course), but on one particular machine, the server socket is opened on a different port ! Always !

Furthermore, I can run the above with the same port multiple times : I just get a different port everytime.

The machines is a Windows 2016 Citrix machine; firewall is handled by Symantec.  I have not sufficient access to get more details.

I believe the above behavior to come from some security software - it is kind of neat, but in my case very annoying.  Note that I can find out what port I actually got, but querying:

```
int actualPort = ((IPEndPoint)listener.Server.LocalEndPoint).Port;
```

I contacted the IT team that manages the machine, they say it is normal because it is a "multi-user" system, and I should read up on wikipedia about ephemeral ports...  Basically I should use an ephemeral port ?

This sounds like a lot of BS to me.  Anyway, whatever I ask for, I get something different....

I've been doing winsock programming for some time now.  This is a new experience for me.

Up to know I have always assumed that, when opening a server socket for a specific port, you would get what you asked for (or fail).

Anyone ever experienced the above ?  Any pointers to some Windows security setting or other piece software that does this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Sounds like the listener is *already* using an ephemeral port, like its internal source code is ignoring the input `port` parameter and binding to port 0 instead. Do note that the constructor you are using is obsolete. You should be using the [`TcpListener(IPAddress, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Sockets_TcpListener__ctor_System_Net_IPAddress_System_Int32_) constructor instead.

Comment: Thx for the comment - I changed to binding to all available interfaces; note that I tried all kind of binds (IPv4 only, IPv6 only, loopback, ...)  I get a different port that I requested and : it is _not_ an ephemeral port at all - the range of ephemeral ports is way higher.  I'm not questioning the .NET TcpListener - I think there must be some mechanism at a lower (winsock ? tcp/ip stack) level that does this.  The big question remains : what is doing this ?

Comment: A security software that changes the port would essentially break all applications. The port must be known to the clients. A random port is worthless. I do not think any software would do that. Note, that clients connecting to a known server port will use a random port on their end. Maybe you are looking at the client port number and not at the server port number.

Comment: @usr : I could not agree more but this is a Citrix machine, not meant to run any server software.
In the mean time, I tested with the server demo program from MS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/finished-server-and-client-code) and it has the same behavior _on_ _this_ _machine_ 

So : back to my original question : what could be doing this ?

Annoyingly, the actual application, btw, starts a WCF ServiceHost to provide a callback endpoint (net.tcp) for a remote service.   And I have not been able to get to the actual socket, to find out what port I did get.

Comment: I've just encountered this problem. I ask for port 49998 but get some random port like 21???. It makes our system useless on this machine.

Comment: Did you ever got this problem solved? We have been running into exactly this problem since the last three weeks. And yes, this must have something to do with Citrix. From my tests I can add that this problem does not occur if the code that tries to create the server socket runs as a service, no matter if the service operates under Local System or under my user account, only if I try to start the code as a program from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

We had a problem that looked very similar to the problem in your question. After more than one month of research, we finally, found the root cause of our problem and got it fixed. In our case the problem came from a next generation firewall from Palo Alto Networks that was rolled out in our company. After the rollout there was a service on our Citrix based virtual PCs with the name "PAN Terminal Server Agent". When the service was shut down, there were no problems. But for obvious reasons these service should be up and running. So we talked to our IT and they were able to make some configuration changes on the firewall (and/or the PAN Terminal Server Agent, I do not know the details), and now the problem is gone although "PAN Terminal Server Agent" is up and running. As you state, your firewall is from Symantec but maybe your firewall works similar to the PAN firewall and also needs a configuration change.